# How to use windows network links directly in nautilus

Tags: networking, windows, nautilus, samba

In the mixed environment of Linux and Windows machines, there is a lot of links shared via IM, emails etc. They point to the same location, but they have different formats.

For example Windows link `\\MACHINE\dir1\dir2\file.xyz` is equivalent to Linux' `smb://MACHINE/dir1/dir2/file.xyz`.

Is there a possibility to translate Windows links transparently in Nautilus or/and shell?

Answer (score 1):

As you said

> in Nautilus or / and shell ?

the shell way:

1. Using `awk`

   ```
   awk -F'\' '{printf "smb:/"; for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){printf "/%s",$i}; printf "\n"}'<<< "\MACHINE\dir1\dir2\file.xyz"
   ```

   *Output:*

   ```
   smb://MACHINE/dir1/dir2/file.xyz
   ```
2. Or via Perl

   ```
   perl -pe 'print "smb:/"; s/\\/\//g' <<< "\MACHINE\dir1\dir2\file.xyz"
   ```

   *Output:*

   ```
   smb://MACHINE/dir1/dir2/file.xyz
   ```

Answer (score 0):

**Shorter `awk`**

`awk '{gsub(/\\/,"/");print "smb:/" $0}'`

Sample output:

```
$ printf "%s" '\MACHINE\dir1\dir2\file.xyz' | awk '{gsub(/\\/,"/");print "smb:/" $0}'
smb://MACHINE/dir1/dir2/file.xyz
```

**Java**

Very primitive, use with caution. Usage: `java translatepath towin[tonix] "/path/to/file"["\path\to\file"]`

```
public class translatepath
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(args[1]);
        if (args[0].contentEquals("tonix"))
            {
                System.out.println(toNixPath(args[1]));
            }
        else if (args[0].contentEquals("towin"))
            {
                System.out.println(toWinPath(args[1]));
            }
    }

    public static String toNixPath(String path)
    {
        return  path.replace("\\","/");
    }
    public static String toWinPath(String path)
    {
        return path.replace("/","\\");
    }
```

Comment: Shorter awk? :)  cool